# debugging nodejs docker image inside vagrant

Tags: node.js, docker, vagrant

to run my node server i use:

```
babel-watch ./src/index.js --inspect 9229
```

this is my docker compose:
intercom:

```
image: intercom
working_dir: /service
command: npm run intercom
volumes:
  - ./intercom/service/src/:/service/src:rw
ports:
      - "9229:9229"
```

code that runs the container:

```
docker run -i -t -v `pwd`/service/src:/service/src -p 9229:9229 intercom
```

but i cant see the debug instance in chrome://inspect/#devices
any ideas?

Comment: Have you opened the specified port in Vagrantfile?

Comment: hosts = [
  { id: '1', 
    name: 'server', 
    hostname: 'server', 
    ip: '192.168.33.109',
    port_maps:[
      {
          guest_port: '9229',
          host_port: '9229'
      }
    ] 

  }
]

Comment: is this enough?

Comment: Looks enough. Try to ssh vagrant and check if this port is used, so you detect on what step the chain breaks.

Answer (score 0):

When running from within a docker container you have to tell the inspector to allow incoming connections from more than just `127.0.0.1` which is the [default](https://nodejs.org/dist/v7.10.0/docs/api/cli.html#cli_inspect_host_port).

Try changing your run command to:

`babel-watch ./src/index.js --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229`